# Given MGF of $X$, how to find $P(|X| \leq 1)$

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

$X$ is a random variable with MGF
$$
 M_X(t) = \frac{1}{6}e^{-2t} + \frac{1}{4}e^{2t} + \frac{1}{3}e^{-t} + \frac{1}{4}e^{t}
$$
I'm asked to find $P(|X| \leq 1)$.

I've been struggling with this one. I know that $E[X] = \frac{d}{d s}M_X(s)|_{s=0} =  \frac{1}{12}$. And I thoguth maybe this is related to Markov inequality, because it gives $P(X \geq 1) \leq E[X]$. But this is only a bound.

Looking at the common MGFs for known distributions, I wasn't able to deduce what X's distribution should be. Any  help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

Note that $$M_X(t)=E[e^{Xt}]=\sum P(X=x)e^{xt}$$

Hence I can read of from the first term of MGF that $P(X=-2)=\frac16$. Try to read off the other terms and you should be able to answer the question.

Comment: wow, that was so much simpler than I thought. It was just a matter of finding that pattern. Thank you.

Comment: But wait, how come those probabilities don't add up? Are you suggesting that X only takes four values 2, -2, 1, and -1? In that case, how come the probabilities don't add to 1?

Comment: Yes, it only takes those $4$ values. The probabiliy sum up to $1$.

Comment: Sorry, can't even do arithmetic any more :) Thanks